# Complex query using Spring data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have a scenario where I need to define multiple predicates and return a specification. The operations I need to perform are 
1. A join
2. In clause
3. Group by clause
4. Count(*) >= some_number
Below is the query that I need to convert as a specification.

SELECT * FROM tableA A  join tableB B
on B.some_id_1 = A.some_id_1
where B.some_id_2 = 18 and  A.some_id_3 
in (1,2,3) 
group by A.some_id_1
having count(*) >= 3

How do I build this specification using Spring Data JPA